# Is there a brush or way to add more vertices as I paint?

Tags: workflow, sculpting

Let's say I have a ball. I click on the ball, and it makes another "ball" on it, but blended onto it like I'm adding on clay. Is there a brush like that, or at least some way to do that?

Comment: You're looking for [dynamic topology](https://www.blender.org/manual/sculpt_paint/sculpting/adaptive.html) from the sound of it.

Comment: my goodness, thank you so much!!! This was the one thing that will let me actually model, so this is wonderful! thank you!!